# Next Date Row with Value 1 in Teradata

Tags: teradata

I need the the below output on Teradata :

```
DATE_HOME   WORKING_DAY
01/01/2018  0
02/01/2018  1
03/01/2018  1
04/01/2018  1
05/01/2018  1
06/01/2018  0
07/01/2018  0
08/01/2018  1
09/01/2018  1

Output required
DATE_HOME   WORKING_DAY Updated_DATE
01/01/2018  0           02/01/2018
02/01/2018  1           02/01/2018
03/01/2018  1           03/01/2018
04/01/2018  1           04/01/2018
05/01/2018  1           05/01/2018
06/01/2018  0           08/01/2018
07/01/2018  0           08/01/2018
08/01/2018  1           08/01/2018
09/01/2018  1           09/01/2018
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking for.  I assume `WORKING_DAY` represents a business day (i.e. no holiday).  What is `Updated_DATE` and how do you want to derive it?  I assume that the date format also is DD/MM/YYYY?  Please add more details.

Comment: Basically Working Day is 0 if the date is holiday, I have first two columns  in a table DATE_HOME AND WORKING_DAY INDICATOR AS 1 OR 0. I WANTED TO DERIVE THE THIRD FIELD UPDATED_DATE FOR ANY WORKING_DAY=0 WITH THE DATE OF NEXT ROW HAVING WORKING_DAYS =1  AS BELOW                                                          DATE_HOME WORKING_DAY Updated_DATE
01/01/2018 0 02/01/2018
02/01/2018 1 02/01/2018
03/01/2018 1 03/01/2018
04/01/2018 1 04/01/2018
05/01/2018 1 05/01/2018
06/01/2018 0 08/01/2018
07/01/2018 0 08/01/2018
08/01/2018 1 08/01/2018
09/01/2018 1 09/01/2018

Comment: Got it.  So, `Updated_DATE` represents the next "working day" date?

Comment: Yes, exactly. So for good Friday 30 March 2018 it should be 3rd April 2018 which will have Working_day = 1 in the table

Comment: Makes sense now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That's a simple task for `first_value`:

```
first_value(case when WORKING_DAY = 1 then DATE_HOME end ignore nulls)
over (order by DATE_HOME
      rows between current date and unbounded following)
```

Change the non-business dates into NULL and then search for the first non-NULL value.

Edit:

In fact there's no need for `first_value` as you sort by the same column, a simple `min` works, too:

```
min(case when WORKING_DAY = 1 then DATE_HOME end)
over (order by DATE_HOME
      rows between current date and unbounded following)
```

Comment: This is a much better way to do it.  Dieter, you are awesome :)  I love your SQL tricks.  You helped me a lot in the past too when I was at Teradata.  Thanks for your tips.

Answer (score 0):

Good lord, this is ugly, but it seems to work.  I don't have access to a TD system, so it's more verbose than it could be:

```
SELECT 
    date_home,
    working_day,
    CAST(
        CASE 
            -- If current date is a non-work day, add appropriate number of days to non-work day to get next work-day
            WHEN working_day = 0 THEN date_home + INTERVAL '1' DAY * (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY update_date ORDER BY date_home DESC))
            ELSE date_home 
        END 
    AS DATE) AS Update_date
FROM (
    SELECT 
        date_home,
        working_day,
        CASE 
            -- If current and previous days were non-work days, group row by PrevWorkDay value
            WHEN MIN(working_day) OVER(ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) = 0 AND working_day = 0 THEN MIN(PrevWorkDay) OVER(ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) 
            ELSE PrevWorkDay 
        END AS Update_Date
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            date_home, 
            working_day, 
            CASE 
                -- Track "baseline" previous date_home value for new group of "non-work day" rows
                WHEN COALESCE(MIN(working_day) OVER(ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), 1) = 1 AND working_day = 0 THEN COALESCE(MIN(Date_Home) OVER(ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), date_home) 
                ELSE NULL 
            END AS PrevWorkDay
        FROM holiday_calendar
    ) src
) src
ORDER BY date_home
```

This assumes your source data is stored in a table called "holiday_calendar".

The COALESCE's are used to handle the first row in the result set, which can't compute values for the previous row, since there is no previous row.

Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Works Brilliant, Thanks Ravioli.

Comment: No problemo :) .